# How to handle eventing in a two vertical column layout using VF

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to put two different forms in two different columns A and B. Initially the form in column B should be disabled and once the user enters information in column A and clicks on button next, it should enable the form in column B. And once you enter information via the form available in column B, the UI should change in column A.

I mean, is there a way to do this kind of responsive web design via visual force pages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a combination of visualforce & html. html for dividing the page into 2 blocks. Salesforce allows ajax actions which allow partial page updates using visualforce tags like apex:actionfunction. So you could call a method upon button click in first  block which allows to update of variable.. the update of variable in turn can display or hide second block. And vice-versa process can also be implemented